# iOS equivalent for onRestart()

Tags: ios, swift

What is the iOS equivalent for `onRestart()` used on Android?

`onRestart()` is called when current activity is being re-displayed to the user (the user has navigated back to it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need `viewWillAppear` method:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    //your code here
}
```

It is called every time right before view is going to be shown. So it will be called when view is shown for the first time as well.
If you want to avoid running your code for the first time `viewWillAppear` is called, you will have to add a flag property and check if it has been set previously.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to capture whenever the scene in question comes into view, there are two cases you might be concerned about:

1. If you transition to this scene (or dismissing/popping back to this scene) from within the app. In that case, use `viewWillAppear`:

   ```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)

       update()     // your routine for updating what is displayed to the user
   }
   ```
2. If your app is running and you press the "home" button (or go to another app), and then later return to the your app (before it is terminated), `viewDidAppear` is *not* called. To detect that scenario, you can observe `.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive`:

   ```
   private var observer: NSObjectProtocol?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
           self?.update()
       }
   }

   deinit {
       if let observer = observer {
           NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
       }
   }
   ```